# Access Spring beans from a servlet in JBoss

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss

I want to write a simple servlet in JBoss which will call a method on a Spring bean. The purpose is to allow a user to kick off an internal job by hitting a URL.

What is the easiest way to get hold of a reference to my Spring bean in the servlet?

JBoss web services allow you to inject a WebServiceContext into your service class using an @Resource annotation. Is there anything comparable that works in plain servlets? A web service to solve this particular problem would be using a sledgehammer to crush a nut.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your servlet can use WebApplicationContextUtils to get the application context, but then your servlet code will have a direct dependency on the Spring Framework.

Another solution is configure the application context to export the Spring bean to the servlet context as an attribute:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
  <property name="attributes">
    <map>
      <entry key="jobbie" value-ref="springifiedJobbie"/>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Your servlet can retrieve the bean from the servlet context using

```
SpringifiedJobbie jobbie = (SpringifiedJobbie) getServletContext().getAttribute("jobbie");
```

Comment: What is the advantage to doing it this way and not using WebApplicationContextUtils?  Either way it's tied to Spring.

Comment: The mechanism to populate the servlet context attribute does not have to be implemented using Spring.  A filter or another servlet that runs at startup can populate the servlet context attribute.

Answer (score 60):

There is a much more sophisticated way to do that. There is `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`inside `org.springframework.web.context.support` that allows you building something like this:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    super.init(config);
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
      config.getServletContext());
  }
}
```

This will cause Spring to lookup the `ApplicationContext` tied to that `ServletContext` (e.g. created via `ContextLoaderListener`) and inject the Spring beans available in that `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: In Spring 2.5.x it should be SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); which handles the rest automatically. Awesome tip btw.

Comment: If you need to access any of the ServletConfig, make sure that you call "super.init(config)" in the "init" method;

e.g.
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    super.init(config);
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, config.getServletContext());
}

Comment: There's a known data access race condition risk in using instance variables in Servlets (if you don't follow the SingleThreadModel). I believe that risk still exists if the instance variable is autowired. OWASP link: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Member_Field_Race_Condition

Answer (score 8):

I've found one way to do it:

```
WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
SpringifiedJobbie jobbie = (SpringifiedJobbie)context.getBean("springifiedJobbie");
```