# Using pure servlets (Java Servlet, no framework) in a project using the Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

We've got some Pure Servlets (pure Java classes following the Servlet API, no framework) that we'd like to include in a project that relies heavily on the Spring Framework.

What's the best way of including these servlets in the project, when all the new code we're writing is making heavy use of Spring 3 features?

Comment: Depends entirely on what they're doing and what you want to do with them. I am not sure about the Spring part, but it at least sounds like that the servlets are doing jobs they actually shouldn't be doing. You should then refactor the code into reuseable classes which you in turn just import/use in those servlets *and* in your Spring webapp.

Comment: What if they're just REST services?  That's a reasonable use of servlets...

Comment: @duffymo: True, but that's not clear from the question :) It still depends.

Answer (score 1):

your servlet container can run multiple servlets, spring is just one of them. why not just include your servlets in the web.xml and see if it works? it should work. spring is not that intrusive, yet (but obviously it already intruded the minds of many developers)

Answer (score 1):

If you declare servlets in the web.xml, alongside the Spring front controller, it most certainly will work.

You just have to be careful when you declare which URLs map to the servlets.  If you send "/*" to the Spring front controller, none of your requests will reach your other servlets.  Be specific about what you need to send to each one.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, servlets cannot be configured as Spring beans. If your question is about colloborating with spring beans from a servlet, do refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467235/access-spring-beans-from-a-servlet-in-jboss) and also [this](http://andykayley.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-inject-spring-beans-into.html)

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides a couple of classes to make this bridging easier.

[`ServletForwardingController`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletForwardingController.html)

> Spring Controller implementation that
>   forwards to a named servlet, i.e. the
>   "servlet-name" in web.xml rather than
>   a URL path mapping. A target servlet
>   doesn't even need a "servlet-mapping"
>   in web.xml in the first place: A
>   "servlet" declaration is sufficient.
>
> Useful to invoke an existing servlet
>   via Spring's dispatching
>   infrastructure, for example to apply
>   Spring HandlerInterceptors to its
>   requests.

[`ServletWrappingController`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html)

> Spring Controller implementation that
>   wraps a servlet instance which it
>   manages internally. Such a wrapped
>   servlet is not known outside of this
>   controller; its entire lifecycle is
>   covered here (in contrast to
>   ServletForwardingController).