# Autowiring in servlet

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, dependency-injection, autowired

i want to use spring autowiring in servlet so here's my code:

```
@Configurable
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @Autowired
   private SystemPropertyDao systemPropertyDao;

   @Override
   public void init() throws ServletException {


   String imagePath = systemPropertyDao.findByID(StaticParam.CONTENT_FOLDER);

}
```

while the `SystemPropertyDao` is annotated with `@Repository`

and my **applicationContext.xml**:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.basepackage" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured/>
```

**web.xml**:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xeno.basepackage.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myimages/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

sometimes the autowiring works and sometimes it doesn't (the reference to the spring bean systemPropertyDao is null), can anyone please tell me if i am missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "autowiring doesn't work"? It doesn't work in specific methods for example?

Comment: @Boris Treukhov (the reference to the spring bean systemPropertyDao is null)

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance(somewhat like in the deleted answer) but what is the actual mechanism are you using for injection? Do you call SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext() anywhere?

Comment: If you configured the servlet in web.xml there might be more than one instance of it.

Comment: @Stefan Lindenberg, yes i did configured the servlet in web.xml, please see my the updated question, any ideas how to solve this case ?

Comment: @Boris Treukhov, i don't understand the questions really.

Comment: @Msaleh There not many ways to access Spring beans from the servlet class (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467235/access-spring-beans-from-a-servlet-in-jboss) so it's interesting which way you've chosen. In the simplest case you may be trying to access the bean before calling SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext so it's null.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I followed the solution in the following link, and it works fine:
[Access Spring beans from a servlet in JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467235/access-spring-beans-from-a-servlet-in-jboss)

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    super.init(config);
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
      config.getServletContext());
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. At first I use `Resource` annotation, it doesn't work, and `Autowired` works well.

Comment: Thank you very much, but why they specifically mentioned in jBoss?? Won't it work in weblogic??

Comment: It will work in Weblogic and even in Tomcat ! This is only the title of the documentation: the solution is actually relying upon the standard servlet api and pure Spring classes.

Answer (score 28):

Remove the `@Configurable` annotation from your servlet and add:

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext (this);
```

at the first line of your init() method.