# Spring Autowiring Issues in a Servlet

Tags: spring, autowired, embedded-jetty

I am having some issues with Autowiring

First off i create an Embedded server

Main.java

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
    CXFNonSpringServlet cxf = new CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet();
    ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(cxf); 
    servlet.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "com.asd.dispatcher.rest.testApplication"); 
    servlet.setName("services"); 
    servlet.setForcedPath("services");     

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/hello");
    server.setHandler(context);
    context.addServlet(servlet, "/*");
    server.start();
```

testApplication.java

```
public class testApplication extends Application  {
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(testServlet.class);
    return classes;
}
}
```

testServlet.java

```
@Path("/people")
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class testServlet {    

@Autowired
private  StatsService statsService;

@Produces({ "application/json" })
@GET
public String getPeople(@QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("1") final int page) {
    System.out.println("======= getPeople");

    //statsService.printStats();

    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

Now my issue is that my statsService is not being autowired in testServlet.java, yet i can autowire it into another class annotated with @Service,

is this because of me using a CXFNonSpringServlet??
or is it because of the way i am trying to Autowire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok i got it working**

Ok so i fixed it (i would post this as the answer but cant answer my own question :/ )

putting the answer here to help anyone else with the same problem

After having a look at the following 
[Autowiring in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843690/autowiring-in-servlet)

I came to the conclusion that a Post Construct method that gets the applicationContext and then the bean would work

Eg: my code would be this

```
@Path("/people")
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class testServlet {    

private  StatsService statsService;

@PostConstruct
public void initStats() {
    System.out.println("============================= Init");        
    ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");  
    statsService = context.getBean("statsService", StatsService.class);
  }


@Produces({ "application/json" })
@GET
public String getPeople(@QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("1") final int page) {
    System.out.println("======= getPeople");

    statsService.printStats();

    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

Although this is not autowiring it does work, if there is anyone who knows how to do this with autowiring i would love to know as it would be far cleaner then the solution i found.

*on a side note i picked up a new issue with this 'solution' to my problem in that the statsService that i have also has other beans autowired in, and it seems although the auto wiring initializes these beans any changes to their state in another class are not reflected in the statsService infact the state of these beans remain unchanged (although that might be the suspected behavior i am still new to spring so i am not sure)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what CXFNonSpringServelt is, but my question is: Have you added the lines above in the context-config.xml file of your application?

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
...
...
<context:component-scan base-package="package of the classes with annotations" />
```

And in your server class you should add the annotation `@Service`

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyService ...
```

And you can use the `@Authowire` like this:

```
public class Client{
    @Autowire
    MyService myservice;
    ...
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i have in my xml config file and i also have tried to annotate my service as you suggested(infact my service is even defined as a bean in my xml), yet it still makes no difference

Comment: Ok, but how do you detect that the autowire has no effect? Do you have a nullpointer exception when you use the variable `myservice`?

Comment: What happen if you add the code below in your client?     `BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("application-context.xml"));

    MyService myservice = (MyService) factory.getBean("myservice");`