# can I inject objects directly to a servlet using @Autowired somehow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have some servlets and some websocket servlets in my java application.

I use latest stable spring framework.

what I know is that because the servlets are not called by a different bean so they are not injectable and I need to get the applicationContext and use getBean to get the required objects.

is it true?

or can I use @Autowired in servlets somehow ?

so I want to be able to do the following:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/ServConnect")
public class ServConnect  {
@Autowired UserDb userDb;
```

Instead of

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/ServConnect")
public class ServConnect  {

UserDb userDb;

public void ServConnect() {
  // get application context somehow
 userDb = appCtx.getBean("userDb");
}
```

thank you

Comment: Please provide your Spring version, "latest stable" can be very different during time.

Comment: Looks like it has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843690/autowiring-in-servlet

Personally I would use SpringMVC which would allow you to easily autowire objects to your controllers. Though if this is not your decision the link above may help

Comment: i use spring framework 3.2.4

Comment: in a websocket servlet I don't have init and i don't have ServletConfig, so the answer that you posed answers the question if it's a regular servlet. but what about websockets servlets?

Comment: The answer is this: If Spring isn't managing the instantiation of your `ServConnect` class, it cannot inject anything.