# Can Spring "live" alongside other servlets in the same webapp?

Tags: spring, retrofit

I've got the a WEB-INF/web.xml file with a couple of servlets, along with a context
listener which I use to bootstrap the application. I'd like to use Spring in this
web application. What's the best way to work Spring into this so I can use Spring's
injection mechanisms throughout the entire application - even in the servlets which
exists today?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Company's XMLRPC service</display-name>
    <!-- Servlet Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.company.download.context.DefaultServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Servlet Declarations -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultTrackDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.download.web.impl.DefaultTrackDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultXmlRpcServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.download.web.impl.DefaultXmlRpcServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Servlet Configurations -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultTrackDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/track</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultXmlRpcServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can Spring “live” alongside other servlets in the same webapp?

Yes, Spring MVC is basically just a `DispatcherServlet` that can make use of a `ContextLoaderListener`.

These two classes are already setup to interact with one or more `ApplicationContext` instances and have Spring manage the declared beans.

Your custom `Servlet` classes are not. If you need to inject a bean into your own `Servlet` instances, you need to get a reference to the `ApplicationContext` from the `ContextLoaderListener` and get the beans you want. There are a few options, whether you do it yourself or use built-in features.

The `ContextLoaderListener` stores the `ApplicationContext` it loads into a `ServletContext` attribute named

```
org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT
```

So you can retrieve it with that (there's a constant for easy use)

```
ApplicationContext ac = (ApplicationContext) config.getServletContext().getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
```

Other options exist, see some of them here:

- [Autowiring in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843690/autowiring-in-servlet)
- [I want to inject an object in servlet using Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054013/i-want-to-inject-an-object-in-servlet-using-spring?lq=1)