# Autowiring on HttpServlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I want to inject a DAO dependency on my class that extends HttpServlet, is this even possible? I don't want to manually obtain the dependency from Application Context, but to have, if possible, real dependency injection on my Servlet instance. I tried annotating my Servlet with @Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ItemsController extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private IItemDAO itemDAO;


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Item> items= itemDAO.getItems();
        req.setAttribute("items", items);
        gotoPage("/jsp/itemList.jsp", req, resp);
    }

    protected void gotoPage(String address, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(address);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

My application Context:

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller" />
    <bean id="itemsController" class="com.test.controller.ItemsController " />
    <bean id="itemDAO" class="com.test.dao.ItemDAO" />
```

Now to my understanding my Servlet (defined in web.xml) is not managed by Spring so my DAO dependency is not getting properly injected, how can I make Spring manage this bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now to my understanding my Servlet (defined in web.xml) is not managed
>   by Spring so my DAO dependency is not getting properly injected

That's right. A `Servlet` is a component managed by a Servlet container. A `@Controller` bean is a component managed by Spring. They are two (usually) conflicting concepts. You should separate them.

Since `@Controller` is just an annotation, you can have a `@Controller` bean of type `HttpServlet` but it will not be managed or used by the Servlet container (or vice-versa).

If you want a `Servlet` which has injection targets, you can use the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843690/autowiring-in-servlet?rq=1).

Comment: so there's no way to achieve DI in a regular Servlet?

Comment: @MichelReap I've added a link that provides a solution to DI. But my point is that your `Servlet` should not also act as a `@Controller`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at those solutions. Correct me if I'm wrong but the `@Controller` annotation doesn't do anything to the bean apart from declaring it as a component, does it?

Comment: @MichelReap It will be picked up by component scanning. The MVC stack (`DispatcherServlet` and `HandlerMapping`s) also processes any beans of type `@Controller` to register any handler methods.

Answer (score 0):

Another more lightweight solution is based on the [`HttpRequestHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/HttpRequestHandler.html). See [this blog](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2012/02/injecting-spring-beans-into-java-servlets/) for a detailed discussion.