# Autowire not working in servlet when performing unit test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, servlets, config

I have a standard HttpServlet. This works fine with autowire when i run it on tomcat, I have accomplised this using the answer on this question .

[Autowiring in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843690/autowiring-in-servlet)

But I cannot perform a unit test on it. It doesn't auto wire beans. I understand that it's because the servlet wasn't initialized with a servletConfig. But how can i do this?

Servlet Class

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    super.init(config);
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
      config.getServletContext());
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
      myService.doSomething();// myService is null on unit test
  }
}
```

Test Class

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/spring/test-context.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
public class MyServletTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests{

  private MockHttpServletRequest request;
  private MockHttpServletResponse response;
  private MyServlet myServlet;

  @Test(enabled=true)
  public void test() throws Exception {
    myServlet = new MyServlet();
    myServlet.init();
    //myServlet.init(servletConfig); //Where can i get this
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

    //Add stuff to request
    .
    .
    .
    myServlet.doPost(request,response); 
    //request goes through but myService throws a null pointer exception

  }
}
```

Comment: did you try add the `@Autowired` annotation to `myServlet` definition at Unit test like this `@Autowired  private MyServlet myServlet;` ? remove `myServlet = new MyServlet();`

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera I followed your instruction and yes it does work!!. But i'd have to add `@Component` to my MyServlet class. I don't think Servlet classes should be annotated with @Component though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: @kryger Yes possibly, But i didn't intend on making my servlet class a bean. So i created this bean through xml only for the test-context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class to your TestExecutionListeners.
And do not create it with "new MyServlet()" Autowire it

Comment: Adding DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListeners, do not help at all. But like @DavidPerezCabrera commented, it works with autowire. Is there a way without adding `@Component` to `MyServlet`

Comment: Yes. Xml config or java config