# Injecting Spring @Resource into a Servlet

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, dependency-injection, annotations

I have the following piece of code, which I modeled on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2523288/787643):

```
public class DeployerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource
    Engine engine;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, config.getServletContext());
    }

    // ...
}
```

But the servlet is not even correctly instantiated. When creating an instance, Tomcat tries to look up the name `com.example.DeployerServlet/engine` in JNDI which results in an exception,

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Deploy Servlet
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name com.example.DeployerServlet is not bound in this Context
```

So, what is the recommended way to inject a Spring bean into a servlet?

Comment: It depends. Do you mind if you get dependencies to spring classes in your servlet?

Comment: I am already fine with `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` in my servlet, so I guess no problem. But it would be nice to have the declarative `@Resource` instead of a direct `applicationContext.getBean()` call.

Comment: Because the Container is responsible for initializing the Servlet, you're forced to use the `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` to achieve what you want. The Servlet is not managed by Spring.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I get that, but the problem is, Tomcat interprets the `@Resource` as a JNDI lookup, and throws an exception before I have a chance to call `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`.

Comment: Have you tried using `@Inject` or `@Autowired`?

Comment: Thanks, `@Autowired` worked! It's a shame that you cannot use the standard `@Resource` here.

Comment: You could post that as an answer :D

Comment: Added an answer with a reference to JavaEE docs that should explain the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Resource` annotation is a [JavaEE element](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html). It's used to declare a reference to a resource. Although Spring can use it the same way it does with `@Inject` and `@Autowired`, in this case the servlet Container acts first. Just replace your `@Resource` with `@Autowired`.

Comment: Note there is slight difference between `@Autowired` and `@Resource`: the later binds beans by name first, then falls back to binding by type; the former binds exclusively by type, using name (as supplied by `@Qualifier` annotation) as a hint only (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html).

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be your build is not properly done. clean your project and rebuild. Your issue will solve

Comment: I use Maven and have been getting this error consistently across multiple builds. Also I do not see how this could be a build problem, as obviously there is no such JNDI name.