# @Resource annotation picked up both by spring and app server

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, annotations, glassfish

We have a Spring 3.1 MVC app packaged as a WAR, deployed on GlassFish 3 application server. The application was once Spring 2, XML-based, and after migration to Spring 3 we slowly refactored it to an annotation-based IoC configuration.

One of the core parts of the application is a custom bean factory, which performs plain JNDI lookups for remote EJBs. However, the parameters of the lookup are stored in an external properties file, which can be changed during runtime - hence the need for a custom factory. We haven't found a way to configure beans produced by the factory through annotations, so the configuration is still in XML like that:

```
    <bean id="exampleEjb" factory-method="lookup"
        class="com.example.EjbServiceLocator" lazy-init="false" scope="session">
        <constructor-arg value="example.ejb.connstr" /> <!-- remote hosts: x.y.z.1:3701,x.y.z.2:3701 - cluster here! -->
        <constructor-arg value="example.ejb.name" /> <!-- JNDI name: ejb/example/remoteService -->
        <constructor-arg value="com.example.service.RemoteInterface" /> <!-- this is interface exposed by remote bean -->
        <constructor-arg ref="configReader" /> <!-- custom bean monitoring configuration changes -->
    </bean>
```

Using a factory here means that the bean class as seen by the container is `com.example.EjbServiceLocator` instead of `com.example.service.RemoteInterface`. Autowire-by-type gets confused and the `@Autowire` annotation cannot match the expected type with the bean name provided by `@Qualifier`. So we have to use `@Resource(name="exampleEjb")`.

Well, it works. With one "but". Every time the application is (re-)deployed, the application sever scans the archive and tries to manage the `@Resource` annotation by itself. And it fails, leaving ugly **SEVERE** messages in the log, causing an increased heart rate in our support department.

What can I do here, to either:

1. Prevent the Java EE container from scanning classes in the application for annotations?
2. Change `@Resource` annotations to something not recognized by the Java EE container?
3. Cause a bean created by a factory to expose the proper type to the IoC container?

Comment: have a glance here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060762/injecting-spring-resource-into-a-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Point 1: 
You can try adding a `metadata-complete="true"` attribute to the `webapp` element in your web.xml file, this should prevent scanning and resolution of `@Resource` annotations by the container.

For Point 2, 3:
Implementing a [Spring Factory Bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) may be a better option, this way you can specify the exact type to expect using the `getObjectType()` api.

Comment: Thanks! 6 years in Java world and still learning basics :) I've applied the attribute in web.xml for now, the other tip will be great for a future refactoring!