# Access Spring beans from a servlet in JBoss got property null

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jboss

I had follow this link: [Access Spring beans from a servlet in JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467235/access-spring-beans-from-a-servlet-in-jboss)
to autowired a bean
But then the properties in that Bean are null ?
So what could be the problem ? Please, help me. I am new with java !!!

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    super.init(config);
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
      config.getServletContext());
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code for MyService. It needs to have some Spring annotations on it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring needs a way to inject the value to your servlet. Try adding a public getter and setter:

```
public void getMyService() {
    return this.myService;
}

public void setMyService(MyService s) {
    this.myService = s;
}
```

Or a constructor that takes your MyService:

```
public MyServlet(MyService s) {
    this.myService = s;
}
```